# Error in passing variable between subroutines in Intel Fortran 2018

Tags: vb.net, fortran

I have been developing a VB .NET program in VisualStudio environment for some years, which manipulates an Intel Fortran 2018 IFX DLL. Until version IFX 2023.2, all programs presented correct results and were verified in debug mode both in VB and in Fortran. However, I recently updated the IFX compiler to version 2024.0 and now the results are being incorrectly presented. After some tests, I observed that the passing of individual variable results is wrong, which does not occur when the results are vectors. The following source codes illustrate the problem.

[VB Code]

```vb
Public Class Form1
    
    'Public Declare Auto Sub ProcessArray Lib "TesteArrayFortran.dll" (
    '    ByRef n As Integer,
    '    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> arr As Double(),
    '    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> sai As Double(),
    '    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> sum1 As Double,
    '    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> sum2 As Double())
    
    Public Declare Auto Sub ProcessArray Lib "TesteArrayFortran.dll" (
        ByRef n As Integer,
        arr As Double(), sai As Double(),
        sum1 As Double, sum2 As Double())
    
    Private Sub Button1_Click(
            sender As Object, e As EventArgs
        ) Handles Button1.Click
    
        Dim sum1 As Double
        Dim sum2(0) As Double
    
        Dim arr() As Double = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}
        Dim n As Integer = arr.Length
        Dim sai(4) As Double
    
        ProcessArray(n, arr, sai, sum1, sum2)
    
        WriteLine($"n      = {n}")
        WriteLine($"sai(0) = {sai(0)}")
        WriteLine($"sai(1) = {sai(1)}")
        WriteLine($"sai(2) = {sai(2)}")
        WriteLine($"sai(3) = {sai(3)}")
        WriteLine($"sai(4) = {sai(4)}")
        WriteLine($"sum1   = {sum1}")
        WriteLine($"sum2   = {sum2(0)}")
    End Sub
End Class
```

[Fortran Code]

```
SUBROUTINE ProcessArray(n, entra, sai, sum1, sum2)
    
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, ALIAS:'ProcessArray' :: ProcessArray
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: n
        
    IMPLICIT NONE
    EXTERNAL :: Check
        
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n
    REAL*8, INTENT(IN)  :: entra(n)
    REAL*8, INTENT(OUT) :: sai(n), sum1, sum2(1)
        
    INTEGER :: i
    DO i = 1, n
        sai(i) = entra(i) * entra(i)
    END DO
    
    CALL Check(n, entra, sum1, sum2) 
        
END SUBROUTINE ProcessArray
        
SUBROUTINE Check(n, entra, sum1, sum2) 
    IMPLICIT NONE
          
    INTEGER,INTENT(IN)  :: n
    REAL*8,INTENT(IN)   :: entra(n)
    REAL*8,INTENT(OUT)  :: sum1, sum2(1) 
        
    INTEGER :: i
        
    sum1 = 0
    DO i = 1, n
        sum1 = sum1 + entra(i)
    END DO
        
    sum2(1) = sum1
        
    RETURN  
END SUBROUTINE Check
```

I believe the error is related to some configuration of IFX 2024.0 which did not exist or had a different behavior until IFX 2023.2. Is it possible to analyze the issue and suggest some configuration that corrects the problem?

Some additional comments:

1. Is it necessary to use the command <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)>? In my tests, there is no difference at all between using it or not when IFX is configured with the STDCALL calling convention (/iface:stdcall).
2. Partial results are only correct when IFX is configured with a) Initialize Variables to Signaling NaN = Yes (/Qinit:snan); b) Initialize Variables to Zero = Yes (/Qinit:zero); c) Initialize Arrays as well as Scalars = Yes (/Qinit:arrays).
3. In my example, the elements of the "sai" array coincide with the elements of the "arr" array. The sum of these elements is 1+2+3+4+5=15, which should be correctly reported by the first element of the "sum2" array (sum2(0) = 15). However, the variable "sum1" is calculated in the same way but results incorrectly in sum1 = 0.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with Fortran, but it is suffucuently far from my experience that I don't know what the tags should be - I have added vb.net but please consider editing to add any other that may be appropriate, it will help you get an answer.

Comment: I really don't understand your comment describing what is wrong. In point 3 it looks to me that `arr` is passed to `entra` not to `sai`

Comment: @Ian Bush, thank you for your comments. Indeed, initially, I believed the issue was localized in the VB module. I attempted to reproduce the error in a small test program that included both VB and Fortran modules. The ‘entra’ array was created with an undefined length to force it to be resized because I suspected that was the problem in my original program. My test revealed that arrays are always correctly passed between VB and Fortran in both directions. In fact, the ‘sai’ array is a copy made in Fortran and is correct.

Comment: However, the variable ‘sum1’ is correctly calculated in the Fortran subroutine ‘Check,’ but it is erroneously passed to the main DLL subroutine called ‘ProcessArray.’ This variable only presents the sum of the 5 elements, resulting in 15. During my tests, I observed that the ‘sum2’ array with only one element is correctly passed between ‘Check’ and ‘ProcessArray’ and subsequently to the VB program with the correct result of 15.

Comment: Despite all my attempts to configure the IFX 2024 compiler, I have not succeeded so far. I emphasize that when the IFX 2023 compiler was installed, all variable passages were correct.

Comment: It may not have anything to do with your issues, but I'd suggest to move toward using the standard interop facilities in Fortran.  I think you'll still need the `dllexport` non-standard attribute to get the function into a dll, but the rest can be handled with a combination of the `BIND` directive on the function and appropriate interop kinds.

Comment: I'd recommend to run under the debugger.  You can do mixed mode debugging to allow you to start out in VB but break into Fortran.  Start with a debug build; debug builds have minimal optimization so if it's still misbehaving, it's probably something you're doing wrong and not a compiler issue---sometimes newer compiler versions are more aggressive and uncover things in your code that aren't allowed but just happened to work.  If your code works in debug but not in release, then I can give some more advice on trying to track down the problem.

Comment: Re your additional questions... for 1, is this 32-bit or 64-bit?  stdcall is meaningless in 64-bit, it no longer exists as a separate calling convention.  I'm not sure about needing the marshal directive; my experience uses the older style declaring as `ByRef` scalar on the VB side and passing the first element of the array.

Comment: @Craig: Thank you for your comments. I would like to inform you that: a) my code is 64-bit; b) it is not necessary to use the attribute <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)>; c) after days of researching and combining instructions and settings in VB .NET and Fortran IFX, I managed to find the solution to my problem. Basically, the variable I want to pass between Fortran subroutines ('sum', in this case) must have the ByRef attribute on both the Fortran and VB sides to be presented to the user. The configuration of the IFX compiler should be: Calling Convention=STDCALL, REFERENCE (/iface:stdref).

Comment: ***** VB .NET Code
    <DllImport("TesteArrayFortran.dll")>
    Public Shared Sub ProcessArray( ByRef n As Integer, ByRef soma As Double,  arr As Double())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim soma As Double
        Dim arr() As Double = {1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1}
        Dim n As Integer = arr.Length
        ProcessArray(n, soma, arr)
      
        WriteLine($"soma   = {soma:#0.0}")
    End Sub

Comment: ***** Fortran Code
SUBROUTINE ProcessArray(n, sum, entra) 
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, ALIAS:'ProcessArray' :: ProcessArray
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: n, sum
    IMPLICIT NONE 
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n
    REAL*8, INTENT(INOUT) :: sum   
    REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: entra(n)
    INTERFACE
        SUBROUTINE Check(n, sum, entra)
            IMPORT
            INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n
            REAL*8, INTENT(INOUT) :: sum
            REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: entra(n)
        END SUBROUTINE Check
    END INTERFACE 
    CALL Check(n, sum, entra)

Comment: END SUBROUTINE ProcessArray
 
SUBROUTINE Check(n, sum, entra)   
    IMPLICIT NONE 
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n
    REAL*8, INTENT(INOUT) :: sum
    REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: entra(n)
    INTEGER :: i    
    sum = 0
    DO i = 1, n
        sum = sum + entra(i)
    END DO
    END SUBROUTINE Check

***** Output Results
***** 06/03/2024 18:07:29
soma   = 15,5

Comment: Now that you mention it, I completely missed the missing `ByRef` on `sum1` in VB, and that's obviously the issue.  You shouldn't need to make any changes on the Fortran side as the arguments should be reference by default.

Comment: @Craig: As far as I could understand, the error I encountered is related to passing variables between two Fortran subroutines and not in the VB .NET x Fortran passing. The available settings for variable passing in the IFX 2023 compiler (Calling Convention) are: a) Default; b) C, REFERENCE (/iface:cref); c) STDCALL, REFERENCE (/ifacestdref); d) STDCALL (lifacestdcall); e) CVF (liface:cvf). Of these options, the only one that doesn't work correctly is STDCALL (lifacestdcall). Unfortunately, it was the option I had been using successfully for years.

Comment: I find that calling convention impact to be very surprising.  The main difference between stdcall and other conventions is that the callee cleans the stack (this is partly the reason for the convention of decorating the symbols with the byte size of the argument list).  Unless maybe the absence of `REFERENCE` is meant to imply `VALUE`, then it would make more sense (though I wouldn't understand why it worked previously).